# Can't connect network in "CentOS 7 on Dell Precision T7610 "

Tags: networking, ethernet, centos-7

I have installed **CentOS 7** on my system **Dell Precision T7610**. While I am trying to connect to network. PFB the details

```
[sigma@localhost ~]$ nmcli d
DEVICE   TYPE      STATE                                  CONNECTION 
virbr0   bridge    connecting (getting IP configuration)  virbr0     
enp0s25  ethernet  connecting (getting IP configuration)  enp0s25    
enp7s0   ethernet  unavailable                            --         
lo       loopback  unmanaged
```

here after

```
[sigma@localhost ~]$ lspci | grep Ether
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 06)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
```

I am a newbie. Please let me know if you need any more details..

Thanks and Regards,
Sreekanth

Comment: post `ip address show`, `ip route show`, `dmesg` and `iptables-save`, please. This will help a lot.

Comment: @Antony There is not result for `code`ip route show `code and iptables-save. Do you need full dmesg results or a grepped one? @nEw gUy and @Antony by the way how highliht the codes in questions and comments

Comment: Full post editing syntax guide is here: https://superuser.com/editing-help

As of dmesg - post the full output under the spoiler. And don't forget about `ip address show`

Comment: @Antony The result is too long. Can I share through Google drive? (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0jB4K9RZ1FsLUNYR2lmSXlBQmc/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is fixed when I tried with other ethernet port `(enp7s0   ethernet)`. I am not sure why the otherport didnt work.

Comment: I had the same problem, same solution on a T7910

Answer (score 0):

According to additional info that you provide, network interface is up, but not configured. You can try to:

1. run `dhclinet` to obtain network settings from DHCP server. It will work untill next reboot
2. run `ip address <your desired ip>/<network mask> add dev eth0` to assign static ip address until next reboot (for example `ip address add 192.168.0.50/24 dev eth0`)
3. edit interface configuration file in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` and [this](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html) guide to set permanent settings for your interface that will persist even after reboot

Comment: I have set the IP address static and it shows connected. I could not access internet/network.

Comment: post `ip route show` and `ip address show` now please.

Comment: PFA the file (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0jB4K9RZ1FsNUJ5a1ppTjBKRkU/edit?usp=sharing) </br> It has `ip route show` and `ip address show` along with `dmesg`